# Saving a dataframe using spark-csv package throws exceptions and crashes (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-csv

I am running a script on spark 1.5.2 in standalone mode (using 8 cores), and at the end of the script I attempt to serialize a very large dataframe to disk, using the `spark-csv` package. The code snippet that throws the exception is:

```
numfileparts = 16
data = data.repartition(numfileparts)

# Save the files as a bunch of csv files
datadir = "~/tempdatadir.csv/"
try:
    (data
     .write
     .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
     .save(datadir,
           mode="overwrite",
           codec="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec"))
except:
    sys.exit("Could not save files.")
```

where `data` is a spark dataframe. At execution time, I get the following stracktrace:

```
    16/04/19 20:16:24 WARN QueuedThreadPool: 8 threads could not be stopped
16/04/19 20:16:24 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exception in statusUpdate
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2@70617ec1 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1bf5370e[Shutting d\
own, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2859]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter.enqueueSuccessfulTask(TaskResultGetter.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.liftedTree2$1(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:347)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.statusUpdate(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalBackend.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$akka$AkkaRpcEnv$$processMessage(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply$mcV$sp(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$akka$AkkaRpcEnv$$safelyCall(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:125)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
        at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
        at     org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1.aroundReceive(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:92)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

This leads to a bunch of these:

```
    16/04/19 20:16:24 ERROR DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file /tmp/blockmgr-84d7d0a6-a3e5-4f48-bde0-0f6610e44e16/38/temp_shuffle_b9886819-be46-4e\
28-b57f-e592ea37ab95
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/blockmgr-84d7d0a6-a3e5-4f48-bde0-0f6610e44e16/38/temp_shuffle_b9886819-be46-4e28-b57f-e592ea37ab95 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.revertPartialWritesAndClose(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.stop(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:174)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.stop(SortShuffleWriter.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/04/19 20:16:24 ERROR BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter: Error while deleting file for block temp_shuffle_b9886819-be46-4e28-b57f-e592ea37ab95
16/04/19 20:16:24 ERROR DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file /tmp/blockmgr-84d7d0a6-a3e5-4f48-bde0-0f6610e44e16/29/temp_shuffle_e474bcb1-5ead-4d\
7c-a58f-5398f32892f2
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/blockmgr-84d7d0a6-a3e5-4f48-bde0-0f6610e44e16/29/temp_shuffle_e474bcb1-5ead-4d7c-a58f-5398f32892f2 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

...and so on (I have intentionally left out some of the last lines.)

I do understand (roughly) what is happening, but am very uncertain of what to do about it - is it a memory issue? 
I seek advice on what to do - is there some setting I can change, add, etc.?

Comment: Try providing an absolute path relative to the HDFS, not your local file system.

Comment: Hi Emre, thank you for your reply. I have solved the issue, but what worked for me was to repartition the data into more paritions (I believe I use 64 atm.) I am unsure why that worked, however, since more paritions means less stress on memory (smaller chunks per node and therefore less memory consumption) I suspect that that was the key to solving this particular issue. I could be wrong though (I will evaluate your suggestion to see whether it solves the issue as well.) Thanks!